# Is it possible to add a description to the linux network interface?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm using openvswitch add-port command and it is creating a Linux network interface for me. I want to store an ID number along with this interface for identifying it. Since my ID number is bigger than 15 byte, I cannot use it as interface name due to the limitation in max length of Linux interface name(max 15 byte).

I'm using the below command to add a port in the openvswitch and to create the interface in Linux.

`[root@host1 ~]# ovs-vsctl add-port br-test sg-11 -- set interface sg-11 type=internal`

Can I use description or some other field to store my ID information in interface?

Comment: Fifteen bytes allow for 4.747.561.509.943 different names (if you only use ASCII characters), that should be enough ;) Maybe you should think about changing your id.

Comment: That's true, but I get this id from some other system, which I cannot change unfortunately :(